# Angularjs Check box Select all function

Tags: angularjs

I have created a filter with different check box options using `ng-repeat`. I am trying to add a select all check box however I am receiving a few errors. Below is the html and code:

```
<accordion>

    <accordion-group  is-open="group.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            <i ng-class="{'icon-minus-sign':series[0].open,'icon-plus-sign':!series[0].open }"></i>
            <span class="title-pos" >{{series[0].title}}</span>
        </accordion-heading>


     <div class="filertType"  ng-repeat="chk in series[0].content">


      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ 'c' + $index }}" name="cc" /> 
      <label for="{{ 'c' + $index }}"><span></span> {{chk.text}}</label>
    </div>



     </accordion-group>


  </accordion>
```

```
angular.module('main',['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.series = [
    {
      "title":"Series",
      "content": [{"text":"Select All"},
      {"text":"1 Series"},
                      {"text":"2 Series"},
           {"text":"3 Series"},
            {"text":"4 Series"},
             {"text":"5 Series"},
              {"text":"6 Series"},
               {"text":"7 Series"},
                {"text":"X Series"},
                 {"text":"Z Series"},
                  {"text":"M Series"},
                          {"text":"Hybrid"}],
      "open":true
    }
    ];
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I think you can add `ng-checked="allSelected"` to each checkbox in your `ng-repeat` loop. Next, add your new "select all "checkbox somewhere that has an `ng-model="allSelected"`

**edit**
Here is a fiddle, same approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8rdr4c/

```
<body ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div ng-repeat="checkbox in checks">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allSelected"/>{{checkbox}}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="toggleChecks()">Select All</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

The JS

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

app.controller('TestController',function($scope)
{
  $scope.checks = ['test 1','test 2','test 3'];
  $scope.toggleChecks = function()
  {
    $scope.allSelected = !$scope.allSelected;  
  };
});
```